# Array of Structs from .txt file

Tags: c++

have a project where I'm supposed to ask the user to input a file name and then take that file and make an array of structs. I'm completely lost! Here is what i have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

string filename;
ifstream inFile;

struct ftballPlayer
{
    int NO;
    string first;
    string last;
    char POS;
    char clas;
    int height;
    char ds;
    int iheight;
    string hometown;
};

int counter=0;
const int MAX_PLAYER=50;
void printList(const ftballPlayer list[],  int listSize);
void printOne ( ftballPlayer two);
void getData(ifstream& inFile, ftballPlayer list[], int& listSize);

int main ()
{
    ftballPlayer list[MAX_PLAYER] ;
    cout << "Enter the name of the input file:  " ;
    cin >> filename;

    inFile.open(filename.c_str ()  );

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot Open Input File."<<endl;
        cout<< "Program Terminates!"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    inFile.ignore (200,'\n');
    getData (inFile,  list, counter);

    for ( counter = 0;counter < 50;counter++)
    {
        printOne (list[ counter] ) ;
        cout  <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void getData(ifstream& inFile, ftballPlayer list[], int& listSize)
{
    ftballPlayer item ;
    listSize = 0;

    inFile >> item.NO >> item.first >> item.last
           >> item.POS >> item.clas >> item.height
           >> item.ds >> item.iheight >> item.hometown;

    while (inFile )
    {
        list [listSize ] = item ;
        listSize++;

        inFile >> item.NO >> item.first >> item.last
               >> item.POS >> item.clas >> item.height 
               >> item.ds >> item.iheight >> item.hometown;
    }

    inFile.close () ;

}

void printList(const ftballPlayer list[],  int listSize)
{
    int looper;

    for ( looper = 0; looper <  listSize ; looper++)
    {
        printOne ( list [looper]  );
        cout << endl ;
    }
}

void printOne ( ftballPlayer one)
{  
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision (2);
    cout << "NO " << one.NO;
    cout << setw(5) << left << "  Name: " << one.first << " " << one.last;

    cout << "  POS " << one.POS << setw(5);
    cout << "Class "<<one.clas<<setw (5);
    cout << "Height "<<one.height<<" "<<one.ds<<" "<<one.iheight<<setw(5);
    cout << "Hometown " << one.hometown << endl;
}
```

Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track? The print out I get is not even close to the text file which is this.

> NO NAME POS CLASS HEIGHT WEIGHT Hometown/High School/Last College
>   60 Josh Mann OL SO 6-4 300 Virginia Beach, Va./Ocean Lakes
>   64 Ricky Segers K/P FR 5-11 185 Glen Allen, Va./Henrico
>   70 Brandon Carr OL RS_SR 6-2 305 Chesapeake, Va./Western Branch/Fork Union Military Academy
>   53 Calvert Cook LB FR 6-0 250 Norfolk, Va./Booker T. Washington
>   51 Michael Colbert DE RS_SR 6-1 230 Fayetteville, N.C./E.E. Smith
>   22 T.J. Cowart CB RS_JR 5-9 190 Virginia Beach, Va./Ocean Lakes
>    1 Jakwail Bailey WR SO 5-11 185 Haddonfield, N.J./Paul VI
>   25 Andre Simmons S JR 6-0 205 Lorton, Va./South County/Vanderbilt
>   34 Johnel Anderson RB FR 5-8 180 Sicklerville, N.J./Paul VI

This is one of three that the user can input but they all have the same type of information. I've looked in my text book and have been hunting online for hours and I can't find anything about doing this when the user inputs the file instead of just starting with a file. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your current output.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that I see wrong right away.

```
struct ftballPlayer
{
       int NO;
       string first;
       string last;
       char POS; // Should be multiple characters
       char clas; // Should be multiple characters
       int height;
       char ds;
       int iheight;
       string hometown;
};
```

I suspect that if you get the right sizes of your POS/ clas, it will work better. Why not make them strings?

Also, there is some issue with reading the last bit. It looks like you have to look for the / to tell the various pieces apart, and I don't see you doing that.

Overall, it would be much cleaner to read this if you could change the format of the input, but I suspect you aren't able to. Comma separated values are very easy to read, as are any other divider.

Comment: I tried making them strings the first run through and had the same results.

Comment: I think I'm almost there, I changed POS and clas to strings and that helped I get stuck with the hometown and school lines. like for the first line Virginia Beach is the hometown and Ocean lakes is the school. I added a string for school but because of the spaces Virginia prints out for the hometown and beach, prints out for the school. How do I make the string include spaces?